# Using flexbox to fill the available width until two items can be accommodated

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two "cells" that sit one on top of each other in a viewport too narrow for them to sit side-by-side.

Until the viewport is wide enough for the cells to render side-by-side I would like the cells to remain at 100% width as the viewport widens.

When the viewport is wide enough to accommodate both cells then I would like them to render side-by-side.

When the viewport is stretched even wider, I would like the left hand cell to remain at its max-width. I would like the right hand cell to expand to fill the remainder of the width.

Can this be done with flexbox?

The following almost works, apart from the following problems:

- once the container is 800px or more the right-hand cell stops growing in width
- the cells do not evenly occupy 100% width when they are stacked on top of each other (AFAICT)

```css
* {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black inset;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell1 {
  min-width: 400px;
}

.cell2 {
  min-width: 400px
  width: /* 100% until the viewport is 800px or more, at which point it should start stretching to fill */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell1">contents of cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell2">contents of cell 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with Flexbox alone, a media query is required.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/813q8phg/)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black inset;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.cell2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .cell1 {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell1">contents of cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell2">contents of cell 2</div>
</div>
```